# Jboss Fuse CXF Expose details

Tags: jbossfuse

I want to know in fuse server where I can find `/cxf` or other root path to expose `webservice`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Comment: Look in the configuration files in the etc directory.